# Visual Basic- ListBoxes

Tags: vb.net, listbox, checkedlistbox

I have 2 ListBoxes.  ListBox1 is populated with 5 selected numbers from a CheckedListBox(LotteryBox) and ListBox2 is populated with random numbers 1-99.  I want to find a way to verify if the numbers in the two ListBoxes match.  For Example, if they matched one number.  It'll say "You've matched one number".  and so on.  I think I'm on the right path with:

```
Dim Matched As Integer = 0
    If ListBox2.Contains((LotteryBox.SelectedItem)) Then Matched += 1
    If ListBox2.Contains((LotteryBox.SelectedItem)) Then Matched += 1
    If ListBox2.Contains((LotteryBox.SelectedItem)) Then Matched += 1
    If ListBox2.Contains((LotteryBox.SelectedItem)) Then Matched += 1
    If ListBox2.Contains((LotteryBox.SelectedItem)) Then Matched += 1
```

But how do I differentiate between the five numbers selected in the LotteryBox?

Comment: Your ListBox will never Contain any numbers.  The intellisence that pops up as you type tells you that `Contains`  takes a control as the argument not a SelectedItem.  MSDN (F1)says the method   *Retrieves a value indicating whether the specified control is a child of the control.* .  Since numbers/strings are not controls it will always be false.  The data is in the items collection.  But it would be better to work with data than controls

Answer (score -1):

Try looping trough the listbox1 that is populated from lotterybox.
Somrthing like this (I didn't set up the objects to test this.)

```
For listItem = 0 To Listbox1.ListCount - 1
  if ListBox2.Contains(listbox1.List(listItem)) Then Matched = Matched + 1
Next listitem
```